# Por qué preventDefault deshabilita el pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex, formularios

Si hago una web sencilla y dentro de un `<form>` coloco un input `type="tel"` por ejemplo, y le agrego un pattern similar a este `pattern="[0-9]{4}[ -][0-9]{4}"` junto a `required` y utilizo un input `type="submit"`, todo funciona normal, si no cumple con los requisitos me muestra el mensaje de "Haz coincider el formato", de lo contrio envia el formulario, y recarga la página.

Pero si ahora en js utilizo el `e.preventDefault();` y ya no recarga, pero ya no me muestra el mensaje "Haz coincidir el formato", y envia la información de todos modos, alguien sabe porque pasa y como evitarlo, el código es sencillo, simplemente un boton y el código js.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnEnviar").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($("#txtTel").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.html">
        <input type="tel" name="tel" id="txtTel" pattern="[0-9]{4}[ -][0-9]{4}" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar">
</form>
```

Como pueden ver, tiene el pattern, pero no lo toma en cuenta, y si escribo letras las acepta y no me muestra la alerta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## Event.preventDefault()
>
> El método `preventDefault()` de la interfaz [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) le dice al navegador que si no se maneja explícitamente el evento, su acción predeterminada no deberá ejecutarse como normalmente lo haría.
> [MDN Web Docs - preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

El evento predeterminado de tu botón es la acción `submit` y al usar el método `preventDefault()` se espera que tal evento lo manejes de manera explícita mandando a llamar al método `sumbit()` más adelante.
Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnEnviar").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log($("#txtTel").val());
        Document.getElementById('MyForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, la forma en la que lo solucione fue utilizando el evento submit, pero, en lugar de aplicarlo al boton lo aplique al formulario:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frmSend").submit(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($("#txtTel").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="test.html" id="frmSend">
        <input type="tel" name="tel" id="txtTel" pattern="[0-9]{4}[ -][0-9]{4}" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar">
</form>
```